# WDT and RadioHead with delay()

Tags: timers, attiny, sleep

The core I use is [this one](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore)
The chip I use is an ATtiny85
I run this using the Arduino IDE 1.8.2
[RadioHead ASK library](https://github.com/Thijxx/TinyHead) (slimmed down)

What I want to do is:

- deep sleep
- wake up every minute
- turn on sensor
- take measurement
- transmit data
- back to sleep

This works when I test it seperatly, where it goes awry is when I combine RadioHead with WDT and then try to use a delay. This always hangs.

Probably a timer issue, I am looking for a work around.
I need the delay because I need to start the sensor, wait .5 sec and then take a measurement. Maybe I should give the ATtiny85 just some job to keep it busy for 0.5 sec?

This is working code, when I uncomment `//  driver.init();` it will fail.

```
// RadioHead ASK
#include <RH_ASK.h>

// Sleep
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>

#ifndef cbi
  #define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
#endif
#ifndef sbi
  #define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
#endif

// Absolute reference PB to overcome inter-IDE issues
#define T_PIN 1 // transmission
#define L_PIN 3 // optional LED pin
#define S1 A2
#define S2 A1
#define BAUD 2000

// Baud rate, receiver, transmitter
RH_ASK driver(BAUD, 9, T_PIN); // pin 9 is non existent

// Watchdog
volatile boolean f_wdt = 1;

ISR(WDT_vect) {
  f_wdt=1;
}

// Sleep
void system_sleep() {
  cbi(ADCSRA,ADEN);                    // switch Analog to Digitalconverter OFF

  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); // sleep mode is set here
  sleep_enable();

  sleep_mode();                        // System sleeps here

  sleep_disable();                     // System continues execution here when watchdog timed out
  sbi(ADCSRA,ADEN);                    // switch Analog to Digitalconverter ON
}

// Setup for Watchdog
void setup_watchdog(int ii) {
  byte bb;
  int ww;
  if (ii > 9 ) ii=9;
  bb=ii & 7;
  if (ii > 7) bb|= (1<<5);
  bb|= (1<<WDCE);
  ww=bb;

  MCUSR &= ~(1<<WDRF);
  // start timed sequence
  WDTCR |= (1<<WDCE) | (1<<WDE);
  // set new watchdog timeout value
  WDTCR = bb;
  WDTCR |= _BV(WDIE);
}

void setup() {
//  driver.init();
  setup_watchdog(8);
}

void loop()
{
  if (f_wdt==1) { 
    pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    delay(500);
    system_sleep();
  }
}
```

Comment: The instruction `bb|= (1<<WDCE)` looks wrong: in the timed sequence, you are always writing this bit to one. The datasheet says (emphasis mine): “2. Within the next four clock cycles, in the same operation, write the WDE and WDP bits as desired, **but with the WDCE bit cleared**”. I would do something like `cli(); WDTCR = _BV(WDCE) | _BV(WDE); WDTCR = _BV(WDIE) | _BV(WDP3); sei();`.

Comment: I do not understand this part of the code well enough to understand your suggestion.  I need to read up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RH_ASK library uses `timer0`, which is also used for `millis` and `delay`.

Quick workaround is to use the standard AVR delay instead.

```
#include <util/delay.h>

...

_delay_ms(500)
```

Comment: This point needs to be made in big bold red letters in the RadioHead documentation.  Many hours were spent {wasted?} trying to debug the issue. +1